# AWS S3 backups for VMware templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, aws-cli, vmware, esxi

**Vmware Esxi** support very few pip or python packages. We have cases where vmware were getting corrupted and our templates are getting loosed. Also we require **periodic backups of templates on aws s3**. I tried the following ways to do:

- Copied the virtual env from my local to esxi server through command line - But it failed as python not supported by Vmware Esxi
- Copied awscli binary to /bin/ path in Vmware Esxi - but packages found to be missing

Can anyone help me provide some solution to upload templates directly from Vmware to aws s3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello i dont know why you say that vmware got corrupted, i'll recommend you not to copy your templates from vmware to aws, just use packer and automate creation for both platforms. It's easy and there are a lot of examples.

Comment: Hi JMHerrer, Can you share some github code or sample where i can get this way around?